# NetBeans connector doesn't refresh itself after updating the code

Tags: html, web, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

**Hello,**

Recently I'v been facing a problem with the **NetBeans connector** on Chrome.
After writing my simple html code, I press the "Run Project" button.
The project opens up on Chrome and the NetBeans connector starts in debugging mode.
Now when I'm trying to change something in the html code (even the simplest - changing a header) it doesn't auto update itself on chrome, therefore I have to refresh the page again myself and then the codes updates itself.

Can someone help me solve the problem?

**Additional info:**
inside the NetBeans IDE I get something in the network monitor saying:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico
Method: GET
Status: Request was cancelled.
```

I don't know much about NetBeans 8.2, but I can provide the info you need.

**The project html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>please work</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Thanks for any help!**